# iOS Branding design

Tags: ios, branding

I am having a View Based Application with `StoryBoard`. but I did not embed the `UINavigationController` to the Story Board.

For the root `UIViewContrller.m` I have add a `UIImageView` property and under `ViewDidLoad` I have added the following command.

```
  self.logoView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,140,172)];
  self.logoView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
```

So that I can display the logo in my first View of the Story Board.

I need to add the same button with same cordinate to all the other ViewControlles in the StoryBoard.

How I can store the cordinates like handling CSS in Web application. Also how I can add the image to all views with proper way. In case if logo sizes get change then I should be able to do few modifciation to change all.

If someone can give me some clue, based on that I can do search and study.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) You can make a custom view by subclassing UIView and implement that view in such a way that suits your need.

2) You can also make a container controller class and then add view controllers in that class.

Comment: SubClassing UIView Solving my branding issue and great thanks. Also I am using a Class file with constant variables to store default Font style, title and other text Font Sizes, Logos X and Y cordinates etc. Is this the only way to store all globle setting.